# Output multiple tables

Tags: sql

My SQL code generates a weekly file (let's call it #final) that I need to separate into 3 spreadsheets (subscribed, not subscribed and customers with no subscription status).

The #final table looks like this:

| Member | IsSubscribed |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | NULL |
| 002 | 1 |
| 003 | NULL |
| 004 | 0 |

I could easily export the table and filter the csv, but I want to automate this as much as possible.
I could simply write 3 `SELECT` statements and uncomment them as I need them, but I'm looking for a way to automatically produce three tables

```
--SELECT * FROM #final WHERE IsSubscribed = 1
--SELECT * FROM #final WHERE IsSubscribed = 0
--SELECT * FROM #final WHERE IsSubscribed IS NULL
```

My desired output:
`TABLE 1`

| Member | IsSubscribed |
| --- | --- |
| 002 | 1 |

`TABLE 2`

| Member | IsSubscribed |
| --- | --- |
| 004 | 0 |

`TABLE 3`

| Member | IsSubscribed |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | NULL |
| 003 | NULL |

Comment: Which dbms are you using? I'd assume it has some kind of tool to export data.

Comment: What's wrong with 3 Statements? What did you want like 3 tables in separate tabs? You can do that with dBeaver, I think SSMS has an option as well. [Edit] your question and specify the dB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question was to create a temp table using `INTO`

```
SELECT
   Member,
   IsSubscribed
INTO #final
FROM <anothertable>

SELECT * FROM #final WHERE IsSubscribed = 1
SELECT * FROM #final WHERE IsSubscribed = 0
SELECT * FROM #final WHERE IsSubscribed IS NULL
```